# CREATE view does not Post the create method from the controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

The create view does not post (or call the create method with the model parameter).

### CREATE VIEW

```
@model Univita.LtcClaims.Models.EpisodeOfBenefitModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm(null, "EpisodeOfBenefit",FormMethod.Post)) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>EpisodeOfBenefitModel</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.episode_of_benefit_id)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.episode_of_benefit_id)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.episode_of_benefit_id)
        </div>


        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.rfb_id)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.rfb_id)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.rfb_id)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.user_id)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.user_id)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.user_id)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.eb_status_cd)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.eb_status_cd)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.eb_status_cd)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.eb_creation_dt)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.eb_creation_dt)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.eb_creation_dt)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.eb_decision_dt)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.eb_decision_dt)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.eb_decision_dt)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.eb_start_dt)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.eb_start_dt)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.eb_start_dt)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.eb_end_dt)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.eb_end_dt)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.eb_end_dt)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.eb_reassessment_dt)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.eb_reassessment_dt)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.eb_reassessment_dt)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.eb_revocation_dt)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.eb_revocation_dt)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.eb_revocation_dt)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.eb_last_extension_dt)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.eb_last_extension_dt)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.eb_last_extension_dt)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.eb_adl_ambulation_cd)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.eb_adl_ambulation_cd)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.eb_adl_ambulation_cd)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.eb_adl_bathing_cd)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.eb_adl_bathing_cd)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.eb_adl_bathing_cd)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.eb_adl_dressing_cd)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.eb_adl_dressing_cd)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.eb_adl_dressing_cd)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.eb_adl_feeding_cd)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.eb_adl_feeding_cd)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.eb_adl_feeding_cd)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.eb_adl_incontinence_cd)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.eb_adl_incontinence_cd)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.eb_adl_incontinence_cd)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.eb_adl_toileting_cd)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.eb_adl_toileting_cd)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.eb_adl_toileting_cd)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.eb_adl_transferring_cd)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.eb_adl_transferring_cd)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.eb_adl_transferring_cd)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.eb_abusive_cd)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.eb_abusive_cd)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.eb_abusive_cd)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.eb_bizarre_hygiene_cd)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.eb_bizarre_hygiene_cd)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.eb_bizarre_hygiene_cd)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.eb_poor_judgement_cd)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.eb_poor_judgement_cd)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.eb_poor_judgement_cd)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.eb_wandering_cd)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.eb_wandering_cd)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.eb_wandering_cd)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.eb_other_behavior_cd)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.eb_other_behavior_cd)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.eb_other_behavior_cd)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.eb_cognitive_imp_cd)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.eb_cognitive_imp_cd)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.eb_cognitive_imp_cd)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.eb_complex_unstable_cd)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.eb_complex_unstable_cd)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.eb_complex_unstable_cd)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.eb_medicare_cd)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.eb_medicare_cd)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.eb_medicare_cd)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.eb_other_ins_cd)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.eb_other_ins_cd)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.eb_other_ins_cd)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.eb_living_arr_cd)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.eb_living_arr_cd)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.eb_living_arr_cd)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.eb_ra_type_cd)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.eb_ra_type_cd)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.eb_ra_type_cd)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.eb_ra_ltr_rcv_dt)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.eb_ra_ltr_rcv_dt)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.eb_ra_ltr_rcv_dt)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.eb_status_rsn_cd)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.eb_status_rsn_cd)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.eb_status_rsn_cd)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.eb_adl_medication_cd)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.eb_adl_medication_cd)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.eb_adl_medication_cd)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.eb_reviewer_user_id)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.eb_reviewer_user_id)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.eb_reviewer_user_id)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.last_mod_dt)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.last_mod_dt)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.last_mod_dt)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.last_mod_by_user_id)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.last_mod_by_user_id)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.last_mod_by_user_id)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.eb_wound_care_cd)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.eb_wound_care_cd)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.eb_wound_care_cd)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.eb_med_mgmt_cd)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.eb_med_mgmt_cd)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.eb_med_mgmt_cd)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.eb_vent_dependent_cd)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.eb_vent_dependent_cd)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.eb_vent_dependent_cd)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.eb_adl_dependent_cd)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.eb_adl_dependent_cd)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.eb_adl_dependent_cd)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.eb_diabeties_mgmt_cd)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.eb_diabeties_mgmt_cd)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.eb_diabeties_mgmt_cd)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.eb_spvn_for_safety_cd)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.eb_spvn_for_safety_cd)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.eb_spvn_for_safety_cd)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.eb_not_listed_cd)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.eb_not_listed_cd)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.eb_not_listed_cd)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.icd9_code)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.icd9_code)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.icd9_code)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.icd9_rcd_type)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.icd9_rcd_type)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.icd9_rcd_type)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.eb_living_arr_other_text)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.eb_living_arr_other_text)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.eb_living_arr_other_text)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}  <br/>
```

### CONTROLLER

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Objects;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Univita.LtcClaims.Dal;
using Univita.LtcClaims.Models;
using AutoMapper;

namespace Univita.LtcClaims.Controllers
{
    public class EpisodeOfBenefitController : Controller
    {

       static readonly DbEntities DbContext = DbContextFactory.GetContext();
       readonly GenericRepository _repository = new GenericRepository(DbContext);
       public IEnumerable<EpisodeOfBenefit> Eobresults = null; 

        //private DbEntities dbContext = new DbEntities();
        //
        // GET: /EpisodeOfBenefit/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            //Eobresults = dbContext.episode_of_benefit.Where(w => w.rfb_id == 3721130);
            Eobresults = _repository.Find<EpisodeOfBenefit>(w => w.RfbId == 3721130);
            return View(Eobresults);
        }

        //
        // GET: /EpisodeOfBenefit/Details/5

        public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            return View();
        }

        //
        // GET: /EpisodeOfBenefit/Create

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Create()
        {

            //Eobresults = _repository.GetQuery<EpisodeOfBenefit>().ToArray();
            //Eobresults = _repository.Find<EpisodeOfBenefit>(w => w.RfbId == 3721130);
            //Mapper.CreateMap<EpisodeOfBenefit, EpisodeOfBenefitModel>();
            //Mapper.Map(EpisodeOfBenefit[], EpisodeOfBenefitModel[])();
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /EpisodeOfBenefit/Create

        [HttpPost]
        //public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection)
        public ActionResult Create(EpisodeOfBenefitModel episodeOfBenefit)
        {
            try
            {
                // TODO: Add insert logic here
                _repository.Add(episodeOfBenefit);
                _repository.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View(episodeOfBenefit);
            }
        }
```

### MODEL

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Univita.LtcClaims.Models
{
    public class EpisodeOfBenefitModel
    {

            //this.eob_service_detail_paid_day = new HashSet<eob_service_detail_paid_day>();
            //this.plan_of_care = new HashSet<plan_of_care>();


        [Key]
        public int episode_of_benefit_id { get; set; }
        public int rfb_id { get; set; }
        public string user_id { get; set; }
        public short eb_status_cd { get; set; }
        public DateTime eb_creation_dt { get; set; }
        public DateTime eb_decision_dt { get; set; }
        public DateTime eb_start_dt { get; set; }
        public DateTime eb_end_dt { get; set; }
        public DateTime eb_reassessment_dt { get; set; }
        public DateTime eb_revocation_dt { get; set; }
        public DateTime eb_last_extension_dt { get; set; }
        public short eb_adl_ambulation_cd { get; set; }
        public short eb_adl_bathing_cd { get; set; }
        public short eb_adl_dressing_cd { get; set; }
        public short eb_adl_feeding_cd { get; set; }
        public short eb_adl_incontinence_cd { get; set; }
        public short eb_adl_toileting_cd { get; set; }
        public short eb_adl_transferring_cd { get; set; }
        public short eb_abusive_cd { get; set; }
        public short eb_bizarre_hygiene_cd { get; set; }
        public short eb_poor_judgement_cd { get; set; }
        public short eb_wandering_cd { get; set; }
        public short eb_other_behavior_cd { get; set; }
        public short eb_cognitive_imp_cd { get; set; }
        public short eb_complex_unstable_cd { get; set; }
        public short eb_medicare_cd { get; set; }
        public short eb_other_ins_cd { get; set; }
        public short eb_living_arr_cd { get; set; }
        public short eb_ra_type_cd { get; set; }
        public DateTime eb_ra_ltr_rcv_dt { get; set; }
        public short eb_status_rsn_cd { get; set; }
        public short eb_adl_medication_cd { get; set; }
        public string eb_reviewer_user_id { get; set; }
        public DateTime last_mod_dt { get; set; }
        public string last_mod_by_user_id { get; set; }
        public short eb_wound_care_cd { get; set; }
        public short eb_med_mgmt_cd { get; set; }
        public short eb_vent_dependent_cd { get; set; }
        public short eb_adl_dependent_cd { get; set; }
        public short eb_diabeties_mgmt_cd { get; set; }
        public short eb_spvn_for_safety_cd { get; set; }
        public short eb_not_listed_cd { get; set; }
        public string icd9_code { get; set; }
        public string icd9_rcd_type { get; set; }
        public string eb_living_arr_other_text { get; set; }

        //public virtual eb_living_arr eb_living_arr { get; set; }
        //public virtual ICollection<eob_service_detail_paid_day> eob_service_detail_paid_day { get; set; }
        //public virtual request_for_benefit request_for_benefit { get; set; }
        //public virtual ICollection<plan_of_care> plan_of_care { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use question tags to specify your programming language and/or environment.

Answer (score 2):

You should change

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, "EpisodeOfBenefit",FormMethod.Post))
```

To

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "EpisodeOfBenefit",FormMethod.Post))
```

in your code, you try to post to Action with name null.